# Casting exception type on child_process exec - NodeJS, Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-cli, child-process

Example code:

```
const execPromise = util.promisify(exec);
try {
    const { stdout } = await execPromise(cliCommand);
} catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof S3ServiceException) {
      // error is of type string so this if-statement is always false
      console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

I'm using AWS s3api CLI `head-object` command to check existence of a object in the bucket through NodeJS `child_process.exec` function. If there is no object in the bucket, s3api throws an error like:

```
Error: Command failed: aws s3api head-object --bucket bucket --key key

An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
  code: 254,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'aws s3api head-object --bucket bucket_name --key keyname'
}
```

Now, I suppose this error is an `instanceof` of a exception class (e.g. `S3ServiceException`).

The problem:

`exec` function throws an error as plain string and I can't do the needed cast/instanceof check.

Is there a way to cast/check what instanceof is an exception thrown out of the `exec` function?

Comment: Even if an error if of type `string`, the catch block still catches it. Is it not happening?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the point of the question. I need to be able to differ exception type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, using `exec` can only result in string-type errors because it runs your command as a separate process which results in string outputs. The `error` being thrown and caught in your example is simply the `stderr` output of the command.

My recommendation is to use the AWS SDK to run your commands: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html. Using that will not only allow you to check the types of your errors, but it will also give you native returns (i.e. you won't have to post-process `stdout` to get your return value).

If you absolutely can not use the AWS SDK and need to make your existing setup working, you can always use regex to check for specific errors but that is a very fragile setup.